# Does the value "NO" gets parsed as "False" in MySQL when entered through Django's fixtures?

Tags: mysql, django, yaml, fixtures

I'm currently using Django 1.2.4 and MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu 9.10.  The model is:

```
# project/cream/models.py

class IceCream(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.code, self.name)
```

The fixtures data in a `project/cream/fixtures/data.yaml` file is:

```
- model: cream.icecream
  pk: 1
  fields:
    name: Strawberry
    code: ST
- model: cream.icecream
  pk: 2
  fields:
    name: Noir Chocolat
    code: NO
```

From the project folder, I invoke the command:

```
python manage.py loaddata cream/fixtures/data.yaml
```

The data is successfully loaded in the database but they look like the following:

```
False - Noir Chocolat
ST - Strawberry
```

Notice how the first entry is `False` instead of `NO`.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue in my fixtures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NO` is treated as `False` because PyYaml implicitly detects that as a boolean value, as seen in [`resolver.py`](http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/trunk/lib/yaml/resolver.py#L169).  If you want it to be the actual string "NO", try putting it in quotes (`""`).